# Different Border Colors in One Class *CSS*

Tags: html, css

I have these underline elements (border-bottom) that animate and underline the whole text "Read More..." when hovered.

[image]

They all work as intended, but I would really like them to all be different colors (each line would use a sample color from the logo to its left).

All these elements are coming from one class

```
    .projectDetails a{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Palanquin', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
    line-height: 1.7em; 
    padding-left: .1em;
    }


    .projectDetails a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: .09em;
    top: 2em;
    border-bottom: .1em solid #A49285;
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .projectDetails a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to edit one attribute within this class (border-bottom color) so that it can have different colors for each project within my portfolio?

Thanks!

Edit: Example of HTML block

```
    <div class='projectHolder'>
            <div class="workImageContainer">
                <img src="../images/twitchLogo.png" alt='Twitch Logo' >
            </div>

            <div class="projectDetails" id="project2">
                <h1 id="snapPoint2">
                    Twitch Redesign
                </h1>

                <h4>
                    Rochester, NY Fall 2017
                </h4>

                <p>
                    Redesigned layout and branding for the landing page 
                    of 
                    a videogame livestreaming website through user and 
                    market research. 
                </p>

                <a class="inTextLink" id="expand2" href="#">Read 
                  More...</a> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html structure for one of the project "blocks"?

Comment: Sure thing! Edited!

Comment: target the class and the id for that div and add your style example "#projrect2.projectDetails a", "#project1.projectDetails a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish could be accomplished automatically using Javascript, but if it is a static page you are working on it is probably easier to do it manually as long as you don't have too many of them to do.

```
.projectDetails.meetTeam {
 border-bottom: .1em solid #{selected color};
}
.projectDetails.redesignTwitch {
 border-bottom: .1em solid #{selected color};
}
```

I know Chrome has a color picker tool you could use to select a color from each image to use for that underline.

Basic code for changing css in Javascript if you want to use that:

```
document.getElementByClassName('projectDetails meetTeam').style.border-bottom = '.1em solid #{selected color};';
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! Made a few changes to your first answer (non JS), and got it working.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a main class and then add an additional class for just the color for each.  This is very similar to D.Kendall's answer above except that is is just adjusting the color, which is all you were asking about changing.  Something like the following:

```
.projectDetails {
    YOUR BASE STYLE
}

.prjectDetails.meet {
    border-color: #COLOR;
}

.projectDetails.twitch {
    border-color: #COLOR;  
}
```

This is just a bit simpler than the answer above and gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass different border color to a the same class, but only one will be used when the DOM is rendered. I would suggest using different class for the colors and calling them separately.

```css
.projectDetails a{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Palanquin', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
    line-height: 1.7em; 
    padding-left: .1em;
    }


    .projectDetails a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: .09em;
    top: 2em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.2em ;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .projectDetails a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .color1:after{content: '';border-bottom-color:#A49285;}
    .color2:after{content: '';border-bottom-color:red;}
    .color3:after{content: '';border-bottom-color:green;}
    .color4:after{content: '';border-bottom-color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="projectDetails">
  <a class="color1">Color 1</a>
  <a class="color2">Color 2</a>
  <a class="color3">Color 3</a>
  <a class="color4">Color 4</a>
</div>
```

.

Comment: The problem with this method is that you are tying the css class with a color.  Typically this is a bad thing.  If you want to change the colors later, now you have to not only change the colors but also change the css classes and re-apply them wherever they are used.  It is much better to use semantic names and then set the colors to those names.  You can then change them to whatever you want them to be and they won't impact the HTML itself directly.